# laravel excel - issue with creating export to xls

Tags: excel, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I have problem with export data from database to xls file. My query return 6 columns but when I wan add next column it's not show up in xls file, it's shows only header. I checked the query and it's ok - returns what I want.

my model class

```php
class CarRaports implements FromCollection, WithHeadings
{
    protected $date_from;
    protected $date_to;
    protected $user;

    function __construct($date_from, $date_to, $user)
    {
        $this->date_from = $date_from;
        $this->date_to = $date_to;
        $this->user = $user;       
    }

    public function collection()
    {
        return DB::table('cars')
                ->select([
                    'cars.id_number',
                    'users.nick',
                    'cars.date_from',
                    'cars.date_to',
                    'cars.price',
                    'cars.color',
                    DB::raw("CONCAT (client.name, ' ', client.prefix) AS client") // not shows up
                ])
                ->join("users", "users.id_user", "=", "cars.id_user")
                ->join("client", "client.id_client", "=", "users.id_client")
                ->whereBetween('date', [$this->date_from, $this->date_to])
                ->where('users.id_user', '=', $user)
                ->orderBy('cars.id_number', 'asc')
                ->get();

    }

    public function headings(): array
    {
        return ["Id_number", "User", "Date from", "Date to", "Price", "Color", "Client"]; 
    }
```

and my controller function

```php
...
     public function genRaport 
     {
        $date_from = $request->input("date_from");
        $date_to = $request->input("date_to");
        $user = $request->input("user");

        return \Excel::download(new UmowyRaport($date_from, $date_to, $user), 'raport_cars_'.date('d-m- 
        Y').'.xlsx');
     }
```

Comment: have you tried using `selectRaw()`? `select(...,  'cars.color')->selectRaw("CONCAT (client.name, ' ', client.prefix) AS client")`

Comment: I guess it doesn't matter because I changed the order of retrieved columns and the last one is always missing